# About python loop

Tags: python, loops, fastq

I have two path

```
path1 = "/home/x/nearline"
path2 = "/home/x/sge_jobs_output"
```

In path1, I have a bunch of fastq files:

```
ERR001268_1.recal.fastq.gz
ERR001268_2.recal.fastq.gz
ERR001269_1.recal.fastq.gz
ERR001269_2.recal.fastq.gz
.............
```

In path2, I have many .txt corresponding to the fastq files in path1:

```
ERR001268_1.txt
ERR001268_2.txt
ERR001269_1.txt
ERR001269_2.txt
.............
```

NOw I've made script to calculate fastq_seq_num from fastq files in path1, see below:

```
for file in os.listdir(path1):
  if re.match('.*\.recal.fastq.gz', file):
    fullpath1 = os.path.join(path1, file)
#To calculate the sequence number in fastq.gz files  
    result = commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fullpath1 + ' |wc -l')
    fastq_seq_num = int(result)/4.0
  print file,fastq_seq_num
```

And also calculate num_seq_processed_sai from .txt files in path2, see below:

```
for file in os.listdir(path2):
  if re.match('.*\.txt', file):
      fullpath2 = os.path.join(path2, file)
#To calculate how many sequences have been processed in .sai file
      linelist = open (fullpath2,'r').readlines
      lastline = linelist[len(linelist)-1]
      num_seq_processed_sai = lastline.split(']')[1].split()[0]
  print file,num_seq_processed_sai
```

OK, now my problem is : I want to create a loop, in which I calculate fastq_seq_num for the FIRST fastq file in path1; then calculate num_seq_processed for the FIRST txt file in path2; then compare this two numbers; then end the loop. Then the second loop starts...How can I desgin some loop to achieve this? thanks!!!

Comment: Probably unrelated to your comment, but regex is way overpowered for this. Why not just use `files.endswith(".recal.fastq.gz"`? Also you're not escaping all of the `.`'s.

Comment: @Brendan: Filtering the output of `os.listdir()` is such a common task that Python provides a module for this. It's called `glob`.

Comment: It's been a while since I handled fastq data files but unless your processing is trivial, I suggest you get to know http://www.biopython.org/, in particular the IO tools (http://www.biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the fastq files, check for the corresponding .txt file and if the pair exists, run your processing and compare the outputs

```
import commands
import glob
from os import path

dir1 = '/home/x/nearline'
dir2 = '/home/x/sge_jobs_output'

for filepath in glob.glob(path.join(dir1, '*.recal.fastq.gz')):
    filename = path.basename(filepath)
    job_id = filename.split('.', 1)[0]

    ## Look for corresponding .txt file
    txt_filepath = path.join(dir2, '%s.txt' % job_id)
    ## Fail early if corresponding .txt file is missing
    if not path.isfile(txt_filepath):
        print('Missing %s for %s' % (txt_filepath, filepath))
        continue

    ## Both exist, process each
    ## This is from your code snippet
    result = commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fullpath1 + ' |wc -l')
    fastq_seq_num = int(result)/4.0

    linelist = open(txt_filepath).readlines()
    lastline = linelist[len(linelist)-1]
    num_seq_processed_sai = lastline.split(']')[1].split()[0]

    if fastq_seq_num == num_seq_processed_sai:
        print "Sequence numbers match (%d : %d)" % (fastq_seq_num, num_seq_processed_sai)
    else:
        print "Sequence numbers do not match (%d : %d)" % (fastq_seq_num, num_seq_processed_sai)
```

I suggest using `glob.glob()` to list your files (as I've done in this snippet).

I also suggest replacing `commands` with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), it's newer and I think commands is deprecated.

Also, reading all lines of a .txt file to get at the last line is inefficient and may cause memory issues if the files are large. Consider calling `tail` to get the last line (*nix only I think).

Answer (score 2):

Are the number of files in both directories guaranteed to be the same? If so, you can use the `zip` function to accomplish this:

```
for fastqFile, txtFile in zip(glob.glob(path1+'/*.recal.fastq.gz'), glob.glob(path2+'/*.txt')):
    result = commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fastqFile + ' |wc -l')
    fastq_seq_num = int(result)/4.0

    lastline = linelist[-1]
    num_seq_processed_sai = lastline.split(']')[1].split()[0]


    print fastqFile, fastq_seq_num 
    print txtFile, num_seq_processed_sai
```

EDIT: As side notes, using `glob.glob()` is almost always preferable to manually filtering the output of `os.listdir()` and the word `file` is a built-in type in Python, which you should never use as a variable name. In addition, to get to the last item of a `list`, you only need to access it with `listName[-1]`. Accessing it with `listName[len(listName)-1]` is unpythonic.